# gluPerspective not working

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing

I use gluPerspective to mainly increase the draw distance, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is how it shows in my code:

```
gluPerspective(0, 70/70, 0, 4333);
```

ratio: The window Width and Height is both 700 and they are constant, in case of wondering.

fovy: I put 0 because, "they" say that using 45 is very nice to draw, but it stops drawing on the screen.

This is the full code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

    WNDCLASSEX wclass;
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hdc;

    HDC p_hdc;

    float t;
    int red, green, blue, x, y, z;
    void update()
    {
        RECT rec;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rec, false);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        t += 0.5f;
    }
    void game()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        float norm = 1;
        float z = 0;
        red = 255;
        green = 255;
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(t, 0, 1, 1);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(-norm, norm, z);
        glVertex3f(norm, norm, z);
        glColor3f(0, 110, 10);
        glVertex3f(-norm, -norm, z);
        glEnd();
        gluPerspective(45, 70/70, 0.01f, 4333);
        glPopMatrix();
        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
    HGLRC hrc;
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpstr, int nCmdShow)
{

    wclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wclass.style = 0;
    wclass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW);
    wclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wclass.lpszClassName = "CLASS";
    wclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wclass))
    {
         MessageBox(0, "Windows Class Registration Failure Detected!\nProgram Can't Be Initialized..", "Failure Detected", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
         return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0, "CLASS", "OPENGL WORLD", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    0, 0, 700, 700,
    HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );

    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hdc, &hrc);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Windows Form Creation Failure..", "Failure", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 1, NULL);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;
        case WM_TIMER:
            game();
            update();
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC win;
            win = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            p_hdc = win;
            game();
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        default:
                return DefWindowProc (hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}
```

What to do?

**EDIT: THE NEW CODE**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

    WNDCLASSEX wclass;
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hdc;

    HDC p_hdc;

    float t;
    int red, green, blue, x, y, z;
    float cx, cy, cz;

    void handle_resize()
    {
        RECT rec;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);
        long width = rec.right - rec.left;
        long height = rec.top - rec.bottom;
        float aspect = (float)width/(float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, 700, 700);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, aspect, 0.01f, 99999);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }
    void update()
    {
        RECT rec;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rec, false);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        t += 0.5f;
        cz = -3;
    }
    void game()
    {
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        float norm = 1;
        float z = 0;
        red = 255;
        green = 255;

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(t, 0, 1, 1);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(-norm, norm, z);
        glVertex3f(norm, norm, z);
        glColor3f(0, 110, 10);
        glVertex3f(-norm, -norm, z);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
    HGLRC hrc;
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpstr, int nCmdShow)
{

    wclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wclass.style = 0;
    wclass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW);
    wclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wclass.lpszClassName = "CLASS";
    wclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wclass))
    {
         MessageBox(0, "Windows Class Registration Failure Detected!\nProgram Can't Be Initialized..", "Failure Detected", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
         return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0, "CLASS", "OPENGL WORLD", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    0, 0, 700, 700,
    HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );

    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hdc, &hrc);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Windows Form Creation Failure..", "Failure", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    }
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 1, NULL);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;
        case WM_TIMER:
            game();
            update();
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC win;
            win = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            p_hdc = win;
            game();
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_SIZE:
            handle_resize();
            break;
        default:
                return DefWindowProc (hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}
```

Comment: what do you actually mean by "draw distance"?

Comment: @derhass the far plane

Comment: You are doing things completely out-of-order in this code and you are also using a single matrix mode for everything. Your projection matrix should be set upon initialization and/or when your window dimensions change. Your general viewing transformations (e.g. `glRotate (...)`) should be done using a ModelView matrix mode rather than Projection.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman So I wrote glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);. The result apparently did not change. Can you write an answer instead of comment, and more specified?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman update() is used to update the Window. Get The Rectangular size of the client window, Invalidate it and Update the window. It's more like Win32 than anything else. It is not OpenGL. I don't seem to understand what is WM_RESIZE, and Google doesn't tell me that either. glViewport didn't change anything. Dammit!

Comment: Woops, I meant `WM_SIZE`. I do not deal directly with the window message pump often. But in any case, that message is sent whenever the size of your window changes.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Does that change anything that has to do with the draw distance? It didn't change...

Answer (score 7):

```
gluPerspective(0, 70/70, 0, 4333);
               ^ nope    ^ nope
```

`fovy` and `zNear` must both be positive and non-zero.

Try this:

```
gluPerspective( 45, 70/70, 0.1, 4333 );
```

**EDIT**: Push your camera back a bit too:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

float t = 0;
void timer( int val )
{
    t += 0.5f;
    glutTimerFunc( 10, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective( 45, w / h, 0.1, 4333.0 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -5 );

    float norm = 1;
    float z = 0;
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(t, 0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-norm, norm, z);
    glVertex3f(norm, norm, z);
    glColor3f(0, 110, 10);
    glVertex3f(-norm, -norm, z);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HelderArmando: That is a different issue altogether then. However, using **0.0** for zNear in a perspective projection matrix ***is*** invalid. In fact, if `gluPerspective (...)` were actually part of the OpenGL API, then it would raise a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error if you tried to do this. Likewise, **0** for the vertical field of view is invalid too - this issue almost never comes up though, because who in their right mind would try to set a 0 degree FoV? :P

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yep. I am just stupid. But like I said, I am still at a very beginner stage of OpenGL... I should put the gluPerspective() function before SwapBuffers() and after drawing, right?!

Comment: @HelderArmando: No, you put it before you need to draw something. It defines the projection onto the image plane (your monitor/window for all intents and purposes) for all things drawn after it is set. You really only have to set it once because GL is a state machine, it remembers all of the states you set until you change them.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman but, when I set it before drawing, it simply doesn't draw anything at all... Am I missing something very important?

Comment: @HelderArmando: From the sounds of things, yes. But you have not included enough information in the original question to answer this comment. I would suggest you edit your original question rather than creating a string of new questions in a comment to this answer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I don't think anything is wrong other than gluPerspective(). It is not changing the draw distance... I know I sound really noob at this, because I just am. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As-per our comments, I made a few changes to your code that are necessary to properly deal with the perspective projection matrix and window sizing. There are still a number of things about this code that I do not like, such as drawing using a timer but this should at least address the small things.

#### New code:

```
void handle_resize (void)
{
    RECT rec;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);

    long width  = rec.right - rec.left;
    long height = rec.top   - rec.bottom;

    float aspect = (float)width/(float)height;

    glViewport     (0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode   (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective (45, aspect, 0.01f, 4333);

    glMatrixMode   (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity ();
}

void game()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); // Do this first
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float norm = 1;
    float z = 0;
    red = 255;
    green = 255;
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(t, 0, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-norm, norm, z);
    glVertex3f(norm, norm, z);
    glColor3ub(0, 110, 10);
    glVertex3f(-norm, -norm, z);
    glEnd();
    //gluPerspective(45, 70/70, 0.01f, 4333); // GET THIS OUT OF HERE!!!
    glPopMatrix();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
}
```

#### Changes to your window message handler:

```
switch (msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 1, NULL);
        break;

    // NEW EVENT: Handle window size change
    case WM_SIZE:
        handle_resize ();
        break;
```

#### Other things to note:

`glColor3f` clamps the floating-point value to the range [0.0,1.0], you were using values of **255** which is only appropriate if you use `glColor3ub`, which is essentially the same thing as `glColor3f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)`.

Comment: Doesn't show anything. I am going to edit the question and put the current code...